# How to obtain AIC with conditional logistic regression using R?

Tags: r, logistic, clogit

I am fitting a conditional logistic regression model with 1:4 controls using `R`. I wish to obtain `AIC` from the model. How can I extract the appropriate parameters based on the object `m`?

```
library(survival)
m<-clogit(cc~exp+ factor1+ factor2 + strata(stratum),data=data1)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you must do it manually, so something like this:

```
2*length(m$coefficients)-2*(m$loglik[2])
```

Comment: `extractAIC()` seems to work too (e.g., `extractAIC(m)[2]`).

Comment: You can also use AIC(m), it will give same result as ExtractAIC and gofm

Answer (score 0):

You could also try gofm function from the support.CEs package